# get a sub document field in $project stage of aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm working with the followings schemas:

**Question Schema:**

```
var Question = new Schema({
      title: String,
      content: String,
      createdBy: {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          required: true
        },
      answers: {
         type: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' } ]
       }
    });
```

**Answer Schema:**

```
var Answer = new Schema({
     content:String,
     createdBy: {
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User',
      },
     isBest: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: false
   },
    createdAt: Date,
    votes: Number    
});
```

I'm trying to do an aggregation where I can have as result the list of all questions with a certain fields like `title`, `createdBy` *(which is going to be populated after the aggregate)*, an `answers_count` and a `has_best` field which is going to be true if a `question` already have a best answer *(an answer with the field isBest equals to true)*.

I've try with the `$project` pipeline:

```
  Question.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    answers_count: { $size: '$answers' },
    title: true,
    createdAt: true,
    createdBy: true,
    has_best_answer: '$answers.isBest'
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    createdAt: -1
  }
}], function(err, questions){
  if(err){
    return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
  User.populate(questions, { path: 'createdBy', model: 'User', select: 'firstname lastname image' }, function(err, questions){
    return res.json(questions);
  });
});
```

Also I've try to `$unwind` the array and then `$lookup` for answers but no results when doing an `answers_count`. This is what I've tried with `$unwind` and `$lookup`.

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: '$answers'
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'answers',
      localField: 'answers',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'answer'
    }
  },{
    $project: {
      title: true,
      createdBy: true,
      createdAt: true,
      has_best_answer: '$answer.isBest'
    }
  }
], function(err, questions){
  if(err){
    return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
  User.populate(questions, { path: 'createdBy', model: 'User', select:
      'firstname lastname image' }, function(err, questions){
    return res.json(questions);
  });
});
```

So, because the `$unwind` in the array, cannot `$size` in answers array to do an `answers_count` field, also when I tried to do `$group` to having uniques `questions id` like this:

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: '$answers'
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'answers',
      localField: 'answers',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'answer'
    }
  },{
    $project: {
      title: true,
      createdBy: true,
      createdAt: true,
      has_best_answer: '$answer.isBest'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: '$_id' }
  }
], function(err, questions){
  if(err){
    return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
  User.populate(questions, { path: 'createdBy', model: 'User', select: 'firstname lastname image' }, function(err, questions){
    return res.json(questions);
  });
});
```

I have this result:

```
[
   {
      "_id": "5825f2846c7ab9ec004f14ce"
   },
   {
      "_id": "5823b9309de40494239c95cd"
   },
   {
      "_id": "582538366062607c0f4bcdaa"
   },
   {
      "_id": "5855d319b6a475100c7beba2"
   },
   {
    "_id": "5878156328dba3d02052b321"
   }
 ]
```

This is the output that I'm looking for:

```
[
   {
      _id: '5825f2846c7ab9ec004f14ce',
      title: 'Some question title',
      createdBy: '5855d319b6a475100c7beba2', // this is going to be       populated,
      createdAt: '2016-11-10T00:02:56.702Z',
      answers_count: 5,
      has_best_answer: true
   },
  {
     _id: '5825f2846c7ab9ec004f14ce',
     title: 'Some other question title',
     createdBy: '5855d319b6a475100c7beba2', // this is going to be populated,
     createdAt: '2016-11-10T00:02:56.702Z',
     answers_count: 2,
     has_best_answer: false
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you've used `$unwind`/`$lookup` ?  Add some sample docs that you are testing your query against.

Comment: I just edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below.

`$lookup` - This stage joins all the `answers` to a question documents.

`$project` - This stage projects all the required fields. `answers_count` - Counts the total the number of items in an `answers` array. `has_best_answer` - Iterates an  `answers` and compares if any of the `isBest` field value is true.

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'answers',
      localField: 'answers',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'answers'
    }
  },{
    $project: {
      title: true,
      createdBy: true,
      createdAt: true,
      answers_count: { $size: '$answers' },
      has_best_answer: 
        { $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: "$answers",
                as: "answer",
                in: { $eq: [ "$$answer.isBest", true] }
            }
        }}
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: it works pretty good, but `has_best_answer` is always `false`

Comment: I just made a change `in: { $eq: [ "$$answer.isBest", true] }`. Do you have the latest update ?

Comment: Yes, I have that, for some reason is always false.

Comment: Do you have property `isBest` as `boolean` or `string` ?

Comment: is boolean, `isBest: { type: Boolean, default: false }`

Comment: I'm not really sure. You can add the data to the post that you are querying if you want me to take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135542/discussion-between-fabio-and-veeram).